# UI Buttons are under embossed Camera Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

On some mobile phones, the camera is embossed and protrudes from the surface of the device. In some cases, this can cause UI buttons to be located under the camera and become obstructed, making them difficult or impossible to use. If you are developing a game using Unity and have encountered this issue, I'm wondering if there are any solutions that can be implemented using C# code.

I'm searched over the google for solution but nothing found.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Put an image of the Canvas component.

Comment: Can you please help me to find out the solution ?

Comment: When setting your UI in the simulator section, you can check the UI on different devices. If you mean a selfie camera, I don't think it will be much of a problem. It would be great if you show the picture of the problem because your question is a graphical problem.

Comment: Can you please check, I have added two pictures
1) First Image Have selfi camera is not cutting any UI, it's starting after the selfi camera.
2) My game UI is under the selfi camera

Comment: As far as I know, even big games like Genshin Impact and Wild Rift have this problem, which seems to be a design flaw in Android. Anyway, I won't promise you. But I am finding a solution that will solve your problem. Because it may be useful for my work in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252912/discussion-between-orela-studio-and-kiynl).